# Do my installed distro and live distro have to match when doing repairs? (eg. bootloader)

Tags: arch-linux, boot-loader, lmde, garuda-linux

Can I use an LMDE-Mint live USB to repair my installed Garuda distro?

I broke my Garuda install after updating, and after restoring a snapshot it still won't boot, which, as I understand, is a result of the snapshot using a previous version of the bootloader. I want to use a live USB to chroot and reinstall my bootloader, but my live Garuda is long gone and all I have lying around is LMDE Mint.

Is this still possible, even though they are based on different distros, or do I have to recreate a Garuda USB stick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

Here is what you need to do :

1. Boot any live Linux distro that will have the necessary software to access your harddisk. for example not all have `raid` or `lvm` included but `lmdm` does so you're good to go.
2. When in the live distro you mount your old OS to a repair folder ex. `/mnt/repair`.
3. Loop mount all necessary folders `/proc` `/dev` `/sys` etc.
4. Chroot into `/mnt/repair`.
5. At this point you're basically inside your old OS you can install new packages and restore/install your bootloader as normal.
6. `update-grub`, `install-grub /dev/sdX`.

Check out [this tutorial](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/chroot-to-repair-system).